# WPF MessageBox result always NO when MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification win7

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

Ok, so I have been researching a lot on this but I haven't found any 'clean' solution to this simple issue.

I'm looking at an application that uses WPF which displays a simple MessageBox with Yes/No options, it works fine in Windows XP but now that we're testing it in Windows 7 it ALWAYS gets the result as No.

```
var result = MessageBox.Show("Message.","Tittle", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, 
MessageBoxImage.Warning, MessageBoxResult.Yes, MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification);
```

Note that the default option is set to Yes and even with that I'm always getting result = No. Even if I change the buttons to OkCancel I always get No. If I remove the  **MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification** or change it to  **MessageBoxOptions.None** it works but the issue with that is that it doesn't show the message on top which will be hard to see for the user.

I wonder if this is a known issue with windows 7?

I used this solution http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18612/TopMost-MessageBox which creates a WinForm to display the message always on top which seems to work fine but I DON'T really want to mix Win Forms with the code we already have.

I'm using framework 4.0.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `"it doesn't show the message on top"`? is this running on a regular WPF application with regular `Window`s?

Comment: @High. It's running as a background application which intercepts the request from another application.